# Setting working directory in SAS

Tags: sas

I would like to programmatically reallocate SAS work dir within a script. In other words, standard set up is ok, but, for some tasks, I would like to have some lines of code that change the default settings... Just for that session.

Thanks in advance for your attention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a library called `user`. When this library is present, sas defaults all datasets to the `user` library instead of the work library.

```
libname user '/folders/myfolders/proj1';

data want;
set sashelp.class;
run;

proc datasets library=user;
run;quit;
```

> The User library enables you to read, create, and write to files in a SAS library other than Work without specifying a libref as part of the SAS filename. Once you associate the libref User with a SAS library, SAS stores any file with a one-level name in that library. Unlike the Work library, files stored in this library are not deleted by SAS when the session terminates.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/69852/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n18m1vkqmeo4esn1moikt23zhp8s.htm